# Copy a bone and the object(s) attached to it?

Tags: rigging

If I have one armature with 3 bones, every bone has a cube (separate object) that is parented to it. Is there some way to copy a bone and the object within the same armature?

I know I can select the cube and the armature and duplicate both, but then I end up with a new armature for every duplicated object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After duplication in object mode, rename all new bones so that every bone and vertex group has an unique name; then you can select  all the armatures and press Ctrl J to join them into a single armature.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem of having too many armatures. Maybe there is a way to automate that with python scripts? Gonna have to learn that soon.

Comment: There's a built in Batch Rename function, take a look.